# Webmatrix support for Image Resizer

Tags: imageresizer

does anyone know of any documentation for Webmatrix and ImageResizer? i think it would be so useful for newbie developers? I've had a look through all the documentation, and i see that there is support for webforms and MVC, but nothing for ASP.NET web pages?

Comment: ImageResizer supports WebMatrix. There's nothing special you need to do for it; just follow the [standard instructions for NuGet or copy & paste installation](http://imageresizing.net/docs/install).

Comment: Oh really? i did try the NuGet install earlier (no other manual setup), but when i tried to change the size of an image using the URL querystring method, it just didn't do anything?

Comment: Did you look at the diagnostics page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In WebMatrix, click the blue "NuGet" button.
2. Search for `ImageResizer.MvcWebConfig` and click install.
3. Open the browser, and visit `/resizer.debug.ashx` If there are any issues, follow the guidance.
4. Add an image file to your project and resize it from your browser by adding a querystring like `?width=200`